# Dropdown of existing posts in a metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

so i want to make a game profile System Like the one gamespot has on wordpress that shows every game's informations In all the posts related to that particular game. I Investigated and ended up  making a new custom post type called "game post_type", and then made a metabox that shows the existing posts of games post type that include game informations, so i can use it to show the game's informations in the form of game profile. but I dont know if it's possible to show game post type posts as drop down on metabox or not and its the right way?

p.s i dont want to use any plugins

Comment: Have you tried using `get_posts()`?

Comment: what you mean? i just ask its possible or not and how i can manage to do that.

Comment: Yes it‘s possible, but have you tried anything yet to achieve this?

Comment: There are a few ways to do this, we wonder which one you tried so we can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot .no i done nothing by now, just want to know thats possible or not and its the right way to do suchthing? also do you have any reference to help me out?

Comment: Not sure if there is an article or tutorial on the web what will exactly tell you what to do. I'm always better of with the codex or developer handbook of wordpress. You might want to look into [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) or `WP_Query` to start with.